# How to update an XML string

Tags: c#, xml

I am wondering how do you go about updating an XML string using XML document...

I will be changing the values of attributes in an xmlDocument (this will be a large string)... Looking online I was a little confused about the proper way to do this...  Here is a sample of what I am trying to do...

```
    //get the value at the key from the form collection
    var value = formCollection[key.ToString()];
    //lookup the specifc <node> in the xml file and match it to the key... should be equal to the path's array found in _EditTemplate values above...
    XmlNode xElm = xmlTemplate.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template/elements/element[@name=\"{0}\"]", key.ToString()));
                //get the value attribute va                    
    XmlAttribute tempAtt = xElm.Attributes["value"];// = formCollection[key.ToString()];
                //Attempt to set the attribute value to the correct value
    tempAtt.Value = value;// formCollection[key.ToString()];
```

Does that seem like a rational way to update an xml String?  Remember, I don't want to save this to a file.  I want to update the string and go from there I need to do more processing...

Comment: Just looked at a quick tutorial... Would doing this work...
        xmlTemplate.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template/elements/element[@name=\"{0}\"]", key.ToString())).Attributes["value"].Value = value;

xmlTemplate.Save(Tmplts);
Only one way to find out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I *just* wanted to set an attribute value (without looking at the previous value), I'd use [`XmlElement.SetAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.setattribute.aspx).

(As an aside, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, I would definitely look at LINQ to XML instead of the original DOM API.)

Comment: Why is Linq to XMl preferred over DOM?

Comment: @saj: It's simply a much nicer API to work with, both for producing XML and querying it.

Comment: @saj, it's much easier to use and integrates seamlessly with the rest of your objects. And when you're done the code is much easier to read.

Comment: How would I navigate to the appropriate XmlAttribute though?  I know about LINQ to xml and I agree it would be simpler to use.  However, it's a long story why I am not using it.

Comment: @DmainEvent: You'd navigate to the appropriate *element* rather than the attribute. It looks like you're already doing that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:
I tried navigating to the element like so...
XmlElement xElm = xmlTemplate.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template/elements/element[@name=\"{0}\"]", key.ToString()));
And the compiler through a nasty error at me... Basically saying you can't do that unless you cast... I am pretty sure you can't cast an xmlNode right?

Comment: @DmainEvent: Why not? You're going to *get* an XmlElement (or you want to go bang anyway, if you're selecting a non-element) so just cast it.

Comment: Does just setting the attribute save the it in memory, or Do I need to do something else?

Comment: It saves it in memory - it doesn't save it to disk of course.